# Remove words of a string started by uppercase characters in Scala

Tags: string, scala, char, substring

I want to write an algorithm that removes every word started by an uppercase character in a string.

For example:

Original string: "Today is Friday the 29Th."

Desired result: "is the 29Th."

I wrote this algorithm, but it is not complete:

```
def removeUpperCaseChars(str: String) = {
    for (i <- 0 to str.length - 1) {
      if (str.charAt(i).isUpper) {
        var j = i
        var cont = i
        while (str.charAt(j) != " ") {
          cont += 1
        }
        val subStr = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(cont, str.length - 1)
        println(subStr)
      }
    }
  }
```

It (supposedly) removes every word with uppercase characters instead of removing only the words that start with uppercase characters. And worse than that, Scala doesn't give any result.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some assumptions, like words are always split with a space you can implement it like this:

```
scala> "Today is Friday the 29Th.".split("\\s+").filterNot(_.head.isUpper).mkString(" ")
res2: String = is the 29Th.
```

We don't really want to write algorithms in the way you did in scala. This is reather a way you would do this in C.

Comment: or just `split(" +")` to allow any number of spaces.

Comment: yes, I know that, or better `\\s+` but after joining words, it will always be with one space, so we may lose some whitespace, this is why I made an assumption, but maybe code will be better with \\s+.

Comment: Well it was much simpler than I thought. Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about `string.replaceAll("""\b[A-Z]\w+""", "")`?

Comment: You probably want to match whitespace after word as well, otherways it leaves them `"_is__the_29."`

Comment: Well, the question was to remove _words_, it said nothing about whitespace.

Comment: Yeah right, but it still has a statement `Desired result: "is the 29Th."` :p

Comment: I dunno, maybe, html collapsed those extra spaces? :) I figure, if stated requirement contradicts a handcrafted sample, you gotta go with the former :)